# Стримминг видео Android

Tags: android, видео, потоки-данных

Доброго дня, дорогие коллеги. Хочется организовать небольшой сервис видеочатов под Android "для друзей", так сказать. Хотел бы по интересоваться в какую сторону копать, либы может полезные или просто статьи. Интересует как серверная, так и пиринговая организация. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ознакомиться с проектом [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org), позволяющим передавать данные и осуществлять видеотрансляции без значительного участия сервера. Тестировал для веба, но когда буду переносить приложение на мобильные платформы, воспользуюсь решением на подобие [этого](http://habrahabr.ru/post/247079/). PeerJs, используемый там, вполне неплох.

Answer (score 0):

Очень удачно может получиться если за основу Jabber/xmpp. На xmpp.org приведены расширения для xmpp касательно видео/голосовых конференций - там это jingle называется. Даются ссылки на бесплатные библиотеки кодеков. Если интересует пример кода, то поищите SIP Sourcery. Их код можно найти на https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11222839/
А для андроида для xmpp есть неплохая библиотечка на Java - smackx